# Calling method presentViewController from the UIViewController in an asynchronous way

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any mechanism to call `presentViewController` method in an asynchronous way?

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.viewController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why would you want to call it in an asynchronous way? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could schedule its execution in the next run loop, I think. Any particular reason?

Comment: I don't know how to explain so maybe it doesnt make any sense. Anyway I will work with it in the standard way (synchronous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, that is by design syncronous. But you might Start another Thread, and do the synchron call there. But i would Not do that.

Comment: Alex, what do you mean with creating a new thread? UI objects need to be excuted in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

the UI method has to be run on the main thread, so it is not possible to call it in an asynchronous way